# What really happens when we Call Thread.start()

Tags: java, multithreading

....As the title of the questions says, I want to know what all things internally happen when we call Thread.start() and when does the start method return and main resume to execute. What all things internally get triggered like registering the thread with scheduler etc..? Also why executors are used ?

Comment: Just one thing: Executors use threads, not the opposite. Executors is just a very well designed Java class. (I mean, it was written totally in Java. Take a look).

Answer (score 3):

When you call `t.start` the JVM creates a new thread of execution (with its own stack). This is done by native code, it is not done in Java. So then the JVM itself calls `t.run` in the newly created thread of execution. This is usually a source of confusions (for starters) as the Java class `Thread` has the same name as the concept `thread of execution`. I guess one can think of these two as: the latter is the **'physical concept'**, the former is its **'abstract Java representation as a class'**.

It usually takes some time between you calling `t.start` in the current thread of execution, and the JVM calling `t.run` in the newly created thread of execution; there's some time lag there as creating a new thread of execution is a somewhat heavy operation.

[Thread.start](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start%28%29)

> Causes this thread to begin execution; the Java Virtual Machine calls the run method of this thread.
>
> The result is that two threads are running concurrently: the current thread (which returns from the call to the start method) and the other thread (which executes its run method).
>
> It is never legal to start a thread more than once. In particular, a thread may not be restarted once it has completed execution.