# Java What Happens When a Thread is Started Until It Starts Running

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, java-threads

What is the sequence of events that occur between calling `Thread.start` and `Thread.run` being called? I ask because mostly out of curiosity, and because I can't seem to trace the native calls to find their implementation, but also to answer some questions I had about what I can expect after starting a `Thread`.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672266/what-really-happens-when-we-call-thread-start) gives a good high level answer, but I'm looking for a **more in-depth answer** + links to source code is possible.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What really happens when we Call Thread.start()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23672266/what-really-happens-when-we-call-thread-start)

Comment: I'm looking for a more in-depth explanation of what happens in the native code + links to native code if possible

Comment: Retracted close vote then.

Comment: *"... I can't seem to trace the native calls to find their implementation ..."*  Install Mercurial and checkout the OpenJDK sources.  It's all there.

Comment: @StephenC I've done that, but I'm not an OpenJDK expert, and can't seem to find my way from the JNI code to the implementation (specifically the `JVM_` code).

Comment: I don't know the answer, but if you're looking for where the magic happens, most of it is going to be in the operating system, and not in the JVM.  The JVM _probably_ is going to call the OS to create the new thread and its stack.  Then the new thread's native code _probably_ is going to make a JNI call into some private `Thread` method that does I-don't-know-what before calling `this.run()`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how every native method of a Java Thread is hooked up, but Java Threads use pthreads in the native layer. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX_Threads

The `Thread#start` method in Java creates (and starts) a VMThread, which is backed by a pthread. The VMThread is backed by JNI and most of its calls wind up at vm/Thread.c (e.g. https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/eclair-release/vm/Thread.c).

E.g. the `VMThread#create` calls JNI method `Dalvik_java_lang_VMThread_create` and that calls the `dvmCreateInterpThread` function in vm/Thread.c

I hope this is a good start for you to start Googling around what exactly happens between Thread creation and its start.

Comment: Thanks! A bit old because it's eclair code, but it pointed me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Streets of Boston pointed me in the right direction, where I found https://android.googlesource.com/platform/art/+/marshmallow-release/runtime/ . I will update this answer as soon as I get a chance to read through the code and grok it.